# How to get the duration of a packet

Tags: omnet++, inet

In omnet++, I created a packet using the following command and I need to see the duration (in second and in bits) of packet.

```
void XMac::sendPreamble(MacAddress preamble_address)
{
    //~ diff with XMAC, @ in preamble!
    auto preamble = makeShared<XMacControlFrame>();
    preamble->setSrcAddr(interfaceEntry->getMacAddress());
    preamble->setDestAddr(preamble_address);
    preamble->setChunkLength(ctrlFrameLength);
    preamble->setType(XMAC_PREAMBLE);
    auto packet = new Packet("Preamble", preamble);
    packet->addTag<PacketProtocolTag>()->setProtocol(&Protocol::xmac);
    attachSignal(packet, simTime());
    sendDown(packet);
    nbTxPreambles++;
}
```

Can anyone please suggest me the syntax of how to see the duration of `packet`?

Thank you

Comment: Could you explain what is `pre`?

Comment: @Jerzy, pre stands for preamble. I am editing the content of my question to attach the block of code where it is being is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every packet has a length (in bits or bytes). The duration (i.e. time of sending a packet via a channel) depends on at least two factors:

- length of the packet
- bitrate of a channel

The length of the packet may be read for example this way:

```
auto len = packet->getTotalLength(); 
int lenBits = b(len).get();  // in bits
```

After receiving the packet, the transmission duration may be obtained using:

```
simtime_t duration = packet->getDuration()
```

Comment: I have already tried this syntax before posting my question, but all time i'm getting 0s as packet duration. I wanted to know the duration of each short preamble generated here. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Your method `sendPreamble` creates a new packet with some content. You may obtain the length of this packet in bits, for example this way: `auto len = packet->getTotalLength(); int lenBits = b(len).get();` However, the packet has not been sent yet so it does not have duration. If you know the datarate of a channel where this packet is sent, you can calculate its duration in advance: `double duration = lenBits/datarate;`

Comment: thanks for explaining so well. It worked. However, i am getting packet length 16 bits where i need 8 bits preamble packet. Would you suggest me which parameter/method defining the packet length?

Comment: Everything is in the presented code: `packet` has the same length as `preamble`.  And the length of `preamble` is set by you in line: `preamble->setChunkLength(ctrlFrameLength);`